# YEAR is missing in many places specifically in questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

There is a little bug : most dates question , comments etc..) the year is lost. 
As the site is now older there are questions that are 1 2 or 3 years old and we cannot tell.
May be I am missreading stuff of there is a trick such as an hovering mouse ...

Comment: Can you give an example? The only time I notice the year not being given is when it's from *this* year (e.g., 2013 as I write today).

Answer (score 11):

If an event is <strike>less than one year old</strike> from this calendar year (thanks quid!), the year is not written.  I recognize that this is not a convention that is immediately unambiguous to new users.  Perhaps we can add a feature request to make everything [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)-compliant.

Comment: This is not completely true AFAIK; yet it used to be like this (at least on SO at some point and I believe on old MO too). But now it is the current year only that is not shown, as Todd Trimble says. See here http://mathoverflow.net/questions?page=205&sort=newest (for Dec 31st 2012 the 2012 is already written, for Jan 1st 2013 the 2013 is not written).

Comment: I say, switch to Unix time! :-P

Comment: OK understood thank you. I favor year every where for better memorization. But well.. .